# How to concatenate matrix?

Tags: c++, eigen

I have 3 vertical eigen matrices and I would like to concatenate them, like in matlab `C=[B1; B2; B3];`. I want concatenate them, in this case: `C(B1.cols()+B2.cols()+B3.cols(),1)`

```
MatrixXd B1,B2,B3;
C<<B1,B2,B3;
```

Is there anything equivalent in eigen?

Comment: By saying a vertical matrix, do you mean vectors?

Answer (score 1):

It is not very clear from your question, but I've understood it as you need to concatenate 3 vertical matrices of size *(n, 1)* to produce a matrix of size *(m, 1)*, where *m* is the sum of all *n*.

If so, than you can try the following:

```
MatrixXd C(B1.rows() + B2.rows() + B3.rows(), 1);
C << B1, B2, B3;
```

For example, this code:

```
Eigen::MatrixXd B1(3, 1);
B1 << 1, 2, 3;

Eigen::MatrixXd B2(3, 1);
B2 << 42, 43, 44;

Eigen::MatrixXd B3(3, 1);
B3 << -1, -2, -3;

MatrixXd C(B1.rows() + B2.rows() + B3.rows(), 1);
C << B1, B2, B3;
std::cout << "Rows: " << C.rows() << std::endl;
std::cout << "Columns: " << C.cols() << std::endl << std::endl;
std::cout << C << std::endl;
```

would produce the following output:

```
Rows: 9
Columns: 1

 1
 2
 3
42
43
44
-1
-2
-3
```

Comment: What is the difference between your solution and the one OP stated?

Answer (score 0):

Libigl provides a [`igl::cat`](https://github.com/libigl/libigl/blob/master/include/igl/cat.h) function. Maybe it will do the trick.